# How to do floating point calculation in ARM?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm, keil

I'm trying to add up two decimal numbers like `1.5` and `1.75`. And I turned them into hex `0x3fc00000` and `0x3fe00000`. And I tried to use `ADD` instrucion to do the calculation but I got`0x7fa00000`, I think the right answer should be `0x40500000`. Is there any way to address this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Floats are handled with NEON extension and additional set of registers. For addition there is `vadd` instruction https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/neon-instructions/vadd

Comment: @vadd NEON isn't available for me. I'm programming for LPC2138.

Comment: @XYWnot If your CPU does not have floating point instructions (and that's an ARM7TDMI-S so it does not), you'll have to either implement these floating point operations yourself or call into a suitable floating point library.

Comment: @fuz But how can I add two numbers while implementing floating point operations manually?

Comment: @XYWnot It's kind of a complicated procedure.  Refer to a standard text like Muller et al. *Handbook of Floating Point Arithmetic* for details.  If you are not familiar with this, it might be a good idea to use a library for floating point instead of implementing it yourself.

Comment: @fuz Okay, thanks!

Comment: it is best to use a soft float library.  for simply adding two non-nan numbers it is quite easy and you can do it yourself.  wikipedia has the floating point formats which apparently you already know so you should have been able to do this yourself.   a little bit of grade school math (line up the decimal points, do the add,  round if desired, normalize the floating point number, done).  try it in C first then asm after...

Comment: and if you had an fpu it is not assumed it is neon, there were fpus for arm before that came along...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct 0x3FC00000 and 0x3FE00000 and the result is 0x40500000

You cannot use a fixed point add directly with floating point numbers. As you can see on Wikipedia or anywhere else the single precision floating point number format is pretty simple.  And most of what you need to know you learned in grade school.

Is it addition or subtraction? In this case addition, okay the easiest. Line up the decimal (in this case binary) points.
Do the addition. Then the floating point part is round as desired and normalize.

Single precision is a sign bit, exponent, and a fraction with an implied 1.fraction. The exponents are the floating part to do the math you need to shift the smaller numbers fraction bits off into the ether until the points are lined up.  Then you can use a fixed point addition.  I did a loop for normalization, but the reality is for addition you cannot overflow more than one bit (0x3+0x3 = 0x6 as an example) so the only normalization for normal numbers (something that doesn't over or underflow or was not a nan to start with) is to either shift it from 1x.fraction to 1.fraction or it is already in the 1.fraction form (for adding two positive numbers).

Seems like a lot of code here, but if all you need to do is add two
normal positive numbers that you know will result in a normal number you can take some shortcuts.  More than I have.  If you do not care about rounding you can take even more.

But there is nothing complicated about add, subtract, multiply, divide for floating point as you can use fixed point operations to complete the task (just like logic does) you just need to prep the operands and normalize the result.

```c
//float fun1 ( void )
//{
//  return(1.5);
//}
//float fun2 ( void )
//{
//  return(1.75);
//}
//float fun3 ( void )
//{
//  return(1.75+1.5);
//}
//
//Disassembly of section .text:
//
//00000000 <fun1>:
//   0: e3a005ff    mov r0, #1069547520 ; 0x3fc00000
//   4: e12fff1e    bx  lr
//
//00000008 <fun2>:
//   8: e59f0000    ldr r0, [pc]    ; 10 <fun2+0x8>
//   c: e12fff1e    bx  lr
//  10: 3fe00000    .word   0x3fe00000
//
//00000014 <fun3>:
//  14: e59f0000    ldr r0, [pc]    ; 1c <fun3+0x8>
//  18: e12fff1e    bx  lr
//  1c: 40400000    .word   0x40500000

#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
    unsigned int a,b;
    unsigned int ea,eb;
    unsigned int sa,sb;
    unsigned int x,y,z;
    unsigned int sxy;
    a = 0x3FC00000;
    b = 0x3FE00000;
    
    //shortcut just do positive numbers
    if(a&(1<<31)) return(1);
    if(b&(1<<31)) return(1);
    
    //exponents
    sa=(a>>23)&0xFF;
    sb=(a>>23)&0xFF;
    //line up the decimal places
    if(sa>sb)
    {
        x=a&0x007FFFFF;
        x|=0x00800000;
        x<<=1; //room for rounding if desired
        y=b&0x007FFFFF;
        y|=0x00800000;
        y<<=1;
        while(sa!=sb)
        {
            y>>=1;
            sb++;
        }
        sxy=sa;
    }
    else
    {
        x=a&0x007FFFFF;
        x|=0x00800000;
        x<<=1;
        y=b&0x007FFFFF;
        y|=0x00800000;
        y<<=1;
        while(sa!=sb)
        {
            y>>=1;
            sa++;
        }
        sxy=sb;
    }
    z=x+y;
    z++; //round up
    while(z&0xFE000000) //should just be if(0x02000000)
    {
        z>>=1;
        sxy++;
    }
    z>>=1; //remove sticky bit
    z&=0x007FFFFF;
    z|=sxy<<23;
    printf("0x%08X\n",z);
    
    return(0);
}
```

Knowing something about the two numbers before we start we can cheat and take some shortcuts, and not bother with rounding.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
    unsigned int a,b;
    unsigned int ea,eb;
    unsigned int sa,sb;
    unsigned int x,y,z;
    unsigned int sxy;
    a = 0x3FC00000;
    b = 0x3FE00000;
    
    //shortcut already know they are positive numbers
    //exponents I already know are the same
    sxy=(a>>23)&0xFF;
    //line up the decimal places (already aligned)
    x=a&0x007FFFFF;
    x|=0x00800000;
    y=b&0x007FFFFF;
    y|=0x00800000;
    z=x+y;
    if(z&0x02000000)
    {
        z>>=1;
        sxy++;
    }
    z&=0x007FFFFF;
    z|=sxy<<23;
    printf("0x%08X\n",z);
    
    return(0);
}
```

Not hard to code in asm.